# How to access Outlook's Scheduler in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, outlook

Please tell me how can i use/integrate/get Outlook's Scheduler in my asp.net application. i mean a person can use Outlook's scheduler to create his schedule..and i can show it in my asp.net application. or if any sample scheduler code/control is available than also give me link of it.. plez help me out.. thanks.

i have just read about "Google Data API" and "Calendar Data API" plez tell me about it.. is it can provide me facilities of good scheduler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an excellent scheduling tool in ASP.net. Have been using it for years and it is great.
http://www.daypilot.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can't reliably use the Outlook API from an ASP.NET application. Outlook is only designed to be automated from interactive client applications.

You can however use the Exchange Web Services API to access the data in Exchange. This is much better than using Outlook even if it were possible because you don't incur the heavy overhead of the Outlook application just to access the data.

[Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb409286(v=EXCHG.140).aspx)

Comment: actually i need to create a appointment scheduler for my application so i though its better to use scheduler of outlook.. plez tell is their an starter kit / open source of appointment scheduler in asp.net

Comment: Don't know of any off hand but DevExpress makes a great commercial ASP.NET scheduler control. It will cost far more for you to develop it than it would to buy it.

Comment: thanks dear.. my company can purchase also. so u its a good one (devexpress).. ok i am checking its details

Comment: i have just read about "Google Data API" and "Calendar Data API" plez tell me about it.. is it can provide me facilities of good scheduler?